# EF Core - How do I add a non-nullable foreign key property?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

ASP.NET ASP Core 2.2 and EF in VS2019.

I have a `Donation` class...

```
public class Donation {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  // other properties...
}
```

Up until now, all donations have been assumed to be in GBP. We want to add support for other currencies, and so want to add a `Currency` class (which would end up as a `Currencies` table), and have a foreign key link from `Donation` to `Currency`. I added the following code to `Donation`...

```
  public int CurrencyID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(nameof(CurrencyID))]
  public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
```

...and the following class...

```
public class Currency {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Symbol { get; set; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<Donation> Donations { get; set; }
}
```

I also populated the `Currencies` table...

```
  builder.Entity<Currency>().HasData(new List<Currency> {
    new Currency { Id = (int)SupportedCurrencies.GBP, Code="GBP", Symbol = "£" },
    new Currency { Id = (int)SupportedCurrencies.EUR, Code="EUR", Symbol = "€" },
    new Currency { Id = (int)SupportedCurrencies.USD, Code="USD", Symbol = "$" },
    //...
  });
```

However, this gave an error when updating the database, as it was trying to set the value of `CurrencyID` to null.

I tried adding two migrations, one with a nullable `CurrencyID` property, and a second where it was non-null, hoping that the database update might run the code to populate the `Currencies` table in between, but this didn't work either. I got the same error about not being able to set the value of the `CurrencyID` property to null as it was non-nullable.

Pre-Core, I would have added a `Currencies` table, then in an SQL script, populated it, then added the column to the `Donations` table, setting the `CurrencyID` property to be the ID of GBP for all existing donations.

To clarify, the `CurrencyID` property should be non-nullable, as every donation must be in some currency.

How do I do this with EF Core migrations?

Someone asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494747/does-ef-migrations-support-adding-not-null-foreign-keys) some years ago, but didn't get an answer.

Comment: Would adding your currencies as part of the migrations an option for you? Using `HasData` on the `DbContext.OnModelCreating`? Or, alternatively, manually adding your insert statements in your migration.

Comment: @ESG I am already adding the data using `HasData` (see my updated question), but it seems it's not being added early enough. Please can you explain more about adding insert statements, as I'm not experienced enough with EF Core (yet) to know how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I had missed setting the default value for the `CurrencyID` property. Kind of obvious now I see it.

I added the following...

```
  builder.Entity<Donation>()
    .Property(p => p.CurrencyID)
    .HasDefaultValue(1);
```

...and the error went away.

On a side note, this gave me a different error about causing cycles or multiple cascade paths. I got around this by modifying the `Up` method in the migration, setting the `onDelete` to `Restrict` rather than the default `Default`...

```
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Donations_Currencies_CurrencyID",
            table: "Donations",
            column: "CurrencyID",
            principalTable: "Currencies",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different ways you could tackle it.

1)

- Generate your migration with your property being non-nullable, and including the data as you are now, but modify the migration so it adds the column as a nullable, and pre-populate the data and alter it later to become non-nullable.

2)

- Generate a migration with the property being nullable, and including the data as you are now
- Make the property non-nullable and generate a second migration, but at the top, manually do your update via SQL.

Comment: Thanks, but as I noted in my question, I tried that and still got errors. As you can see from the answer I posted just before yours, the main problem was that I forgot to set the default value for the `CurrencyID` property. Once I did that, and sorted out the cascading delete issue, it all worked fine. Thanks anyway